# merge sort algorithm for stream data

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I am reading about merge sort at below link

http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_sorting.aspx

> Merge sort's claim to fame is that it can easily be modified to handle
>   sequential data such as from a stream or a generator. Another huge
>   benefit is that when written carefully, merge sort does not require
>   that all items be present. It can sort an unknown number of items
>   coming in from a stream or generator, which is a very useful property.

My questions are

1.My understanding is that merge sort requires complete array because we have to divide array in between and sort independently followed by merge.How merge sort algorithm works if not all items are present?

2. Give a algorithm in simple terms how merge sort algorithm used for items coming in from a stream?

Comment: 298 questions, 126 upvotes - you should really upvote more, at least for those who give good answers to your questions

Answer (score 0):

The answers to 1 and 2 are somewhat related.

1. You can still perform a `mergesort` with an incomplete array, which would leave you with a sorted, partially complete array.  The running time would still be `O(n lg n)`.  As for inserting the remaining items, you could either merge the partial array with the new items, or insert the new items one at a time, q.v. part 2 below.  Inserting the remaining items one at a time would work best if the original array is nearly complete.
2. Assuming you are starting with a sorted array of numbers, as new numbers came in from the stream one-by-one, you would not have to run another `mergesort`.  Instead, you could simply walk through the sorted array in `O(n)` time and insert each new item coming from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort works by dividing the list into subsets, sorting the subsets then putting it all back together. If the subset is one element long (the item being streamed in) then it is already sorted and just needs to be put in with the existing set of elements. Technically, I would call this insertion sort. The hard part here is determining where to put the new element. You could use an array which makes finding the right place quite easy but adding new items requires moving data around to make space (sometimes reallocating the array). Alternatively, you could store the data as a linked list so adding items is trivial but determining where to put new items is trickier. Swings and roundabouts.